# Template hints will not turn off, even after clearing cache?

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento ver. 1.9.2.4

I know this is a common problem and I've followed the advise I found, but nothing is working.

Here is what I have tried:

Disabled blocks
Made sure System / Config / Advanced / Developer / Main Site / Template Path Hints is turned off
Cleared cache (no change)
Turned blocks on
Cleared cache (no change)

Advise very welcome please

Comment: check in store view may be enabled there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a prolonged investigation, I have found that the translate inline option was enabled in front-end and backend, disenabling resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In database go to `core_config_data` table and check if the value for `dev/debug/template_hints` path is `0`

Comment: Odd, database `core_config_data table`, `dev/debug/template_hints path` is 0

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Current Configuration Scope` in the upper left hand corner of the **Configuration** page and check this setting on the `default store view`.

The configuration can be overridden on this view if  **Use Website** is unchecked on 'default store view`.